# Bug java. I don't know how to fix it

Tags: java

I'm learning java and there's a bug into this code. I simply don't know howto fix it.

Here's the code:

```
public class CountLettersInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] chars = createArray();

    System.out.println("The lowercase letters are:");
    displayArray(chars);    

    int[] counts = countLetters(chars);

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("The occurence of each letter are: ");
    displayCounts(counts);
    }

    public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++);
            if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0);
                System.out.println(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a'));
                else 
                    System.out.println(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a') + " ");


    }

    public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars) {
        //Declare and create an array of 26 int
        int[] counts = new int[26];

        //For each lowercase letter in the array, count it
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++);
            counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;

        return counts;
    }

    public static void displayArray(char[] chars) {
        //Display the characters in the array 20/line
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++);
            if ((i + 1) % 20 == 0)
                System.out.println(chars[i]);
            else
                System.out.print(chars[i] + " ");
    }

    public static char[] createArray() {
        //Declare the array of characters and create it
        char[] chars = new char[100];

        //Create lowercase characters randomly and assign them to array
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++);
            chars[i] = RamdomCharacter.getRandomLowerCaseLetter();
        //This return the array 
        return chars;
    }

}
```

I'm coding it with Eclypse and the software is telling me those two things:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    i cannot be resolved to a variable
    RamdomCharacter cannot be resolved
```

How am I supose to fix this?

Comment: As Eclipse said, RamdomCharacter class does not exist. If you have it in your project, you must import it at the top of this class. And your for each must be written as this: for (...) { actions; }

Comment: Please press `Ctrl+Shift+F` in Eclipse from time to time to see how your code really looks like (this would show you for example that you have `;` right after `for(..)`). Also what is `RamdomCharacter`? Is it possible that you want to access *Ra**n**domCharacter*?

Comment: Learn to use braces (`{` and `}`) for your loops and `if/else` constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to a class `RamdomCharacter`.

1. I think you mean `RandomCharacter`
2. Do you have such a class in your project?

Answer (score 2):

You're putting `;`s at the end of your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++);
                                       ^
```

Get rid of those, and surround the loop bodies with `{}`.

The problem right now is that `i` exists *only* in the scope of the loop. But, you've terminated the loop scope by adding the `;`, so when you reference `i` outside you receive a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++);    <--- remove the ;
      counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;
```

The `;` ends a statement. Therefore the `counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;` is not encapsulated in the for loop as you'd expect. So it can't access that `i` variable.

- You've done the same thing two other times also
- use brackets `{}` to encapsulate your loops

Answer (score 0):

For you second issue, I don't see where the `RamdomCharacter` class is defined, but my guess would be that it's actually called `RandomCharacter`, with an `n`

Answer (score 0):

apart from the problems noted by other two answer it seems RamdomCharacter  is not imported properly. Thats why you are getting such error. import the class properly.